# conversion from `Header*' to non-scalar type `

Tags: c++

can anyone please tell the problem with code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Header
{
};


int main()
{
        Header* _start;
        vector<Header>::iterator it = _start;
        return 0;
}
```

### error:

conversion from `Header*'` to non-scalar type:

```
   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Header*, std::vector<Header,
   std::allocator<Header> > >' requested
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
vector<Header>::iterator it = _start;
```

to

```
vector<Header>::iterator it(_start);
```

**EDIT:** 
The problem is when you using an assignment, compiler expand it to such code:

```
vector<Header>::iterator it = static_cast<vector<Header>::iterator>(_start);
```

But there are no implicit or explicit type conversion from pointer to iterator.

On the other side, iterator has a constructor `T::iterator(const T *&)` which you can use.

**EDIT2:**
That's not so good idea to mix pointers (C-style) and iterators (C++-style). When you are using containers (C++-style) instead of arrays (C-style), you don't need to work with raw pointers. Containers provide methods to get a different iterators.

For example, you should use `v.begin() + i` instead of `(T*)&v[i]`

Answer (score 0):

It means that `vector<Header>::iterator` isn't the same type as `Header*`.

If you want to initialise it just write:

```
vector<Header>::iterator it;
```

If you want to make it point at something valid you'll need to get an iterator from a `vector` object.

```
vector<Header> headers;

it = headers.begin();
//or
it = headers.end();
```